# Calling JS function without parentheses

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today I came across JS syntax I see for the first time. In [Microsoft MSSQL client for nodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) there is this example:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
 
async () => {
    try {
        // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
        await sql.connect('mssql://username:password@localhost/database')
        const result = await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
        console.dir(result)
    } catch (err) {
        // ... error checks
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this line:

```
await sql.query`select * from mytable where id = ${value}`
```

It looks like `query` is a method on `sql` object but how it can be called like this? Is this appended interpolated string passed as argument? What is the name of this JS feature?

Comment: It is called [string template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and has a different purpose. Here it seems the developer abused of the notation to call `sql.query()` without parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature called 'Tagged templates'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals